# Chainig functions with observables fails to retrieve data

Tags: angular, typescript

Am performing one function after another has completed

This is what i have tried

```
  ngOnInit () {
    this.subscriptions.add(
     this.route.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.truckdetails = params;
         this.getChecklistCategory();
       })
    )
 }


  getChecklistCategory(){
     this._checklistCategoryProvider.getAll()
        .subscribe(
           res=>{
                console.log("got data here") //this is never executed
                ///this.checklists = res //this outputs data in frontend
              },
            err=>{
               console.log("error is here")//this is not executed
              }
         )


    }
```

The second function is never executed as check for both res and error

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Does your first subscribe() call work ? Where you call getChecklistCategory.

Comment: yes a console.log() there works.

Comment: Might be an error somewhere else, I don't see anything obviously wrong in the posted code.